# Relation between set and inverse transformation applied on set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have problem with the following exercise. Let $f:M \rightarrow N$ a map and $M' \subseteq M$ and $N' \subseteq image(f) \subseteq N$. Show $M' \subseteq f^{-1}(f(M'))$. Intuitively, I can imagine the to be proven statement is true but I can't show how this is possible. So I try:

$f^{-1}: N \rightarrow M$

Let $x \in M' \rightarrow x \in M$.

$f(M') \subseteq N \rightarrow f^{-1}(f(M')) \subseteq M$

I thought if i can somehow prove $M \subseteq f^{-1}(f(M'))$, then I can also prove the statement. However,  $M \subseteq f^{-1}(f(M'))$ doesn't make sense to me ... Any tips or suggestions would be great.

Comment: Note that $f^{-1}$ doesn't necessarily exist here. The set $f^{-1}(A)$ is just the set of all elements $x$ such that $f(x)\in A$.

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip! Tho I'm still stuck. Can you help me a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to show $M' \subset  f^{-1}(f(M'))$. Let $x$ be an element of $M'$. Let's show that $x \in f^{-1}(f(M'))$. To show this, we must show that $f(x) \in f(M')$. This is obvious as $x$ belongs to $M'$. That's the proof!